# partition of a group and cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to solve the problem 2.10.3 from Artin's Algebra first edition:

> Let P be a partition of a group G with the property that for any pair of elements A, B of the partition, the product set AB is contained entirely within another element C of the partition. Let N be the element of P which contains 1. Prove that N is a normal subgroup of G and that P is the set of its cosets.

I manage to prove that N is a group, that is normal, and that is't cosets are contained in the elements of the partition but I don't see how to prove the converse inclusion, any hint?

Comment: So you have $Ng \le P_1$ for some partition element $P_1$, $Ng^{-1} \le P_2$, giving $P_1P_2 \le N$, hence $P_1Ng^{-1} \le N$, so $P_1 \le Ng$.

Comment: That's it. Thanks Derek!

Comment: .... so $P_1 N \le Ng$? @DerekHolt

Comment: @athos I don't understand what you are asking. I gave a hint which enabled Jose Fernandez to complete huis solution.

Comment: @DerekHolt I guess you comment has an typo at the end, "so $P_1 \le Ng$" might be "so $P_1 N \le Ng$"?

Comment: No, there was no typo on my comment. $P_1 \le Ng$ is what we needed to prove.