# partition of a group to have normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $P$ be a partition of a group $G$ with the property that for any pair of elements $A, B$ of the partition, the product set $AB$ is contained entirely within another element $C$ of the partition. Let $N$ be the element of $P$ which contains $1$. Prove that $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and that $P$ is the set of its cosets.

Also see [here(same question)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1458212/partition-of-a-group-and-cosets)

I feel so foolish for I could not solve this problem. It is easy to see that $N$ is a subgroup since inverse is in $N$. Let $A,N\in P$, then easy to note that $A\subset AN$, but $AN$ is a subset of different partition. So the partition is the set of all cosets of $N$.

**But how to show** that $N$ is normal subgroup? I understood that the link I gave tried to show that in comment section... but I could not understand the notations!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, $N$ is the subset of the partition that contains $1$.

For any $A\in \mathcal P$, we indeed have $A\subseteq AN$ because $1\in N$, but this implies that $AN$ must be a subset of the *same* element, $A$. 
[Say, $AN\subseteq B\in \mathcal P$, then $\emptyset\ne A\subseteq B$, so they intersect, hence $A=B$ must hold by the partition.]

It means we have $A=AN$, and similarly $NA=A$ for all $A\in \mathcal P$.

Now, for any $a\in G$, we have a unique $A\in \mathcal P$ containing $a$, let $B\in \mathcal P$ the subset containing $a^{-1}$, and with these,
$$aNa^{-1}\subseteq ANB = AB$$
But, as $1\in AB\cap N$, we have $AB\subseteq N$ by hypothesis.

---

**Alternative proof:** Equip $\mathcal P$ with group structure and define the obvious function $G\to \mathcal P$. It will be a homomorphism with kernel $N$.