# Is a group formed by a partition always a quotient group?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

> Let $G$ be a group. If $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, the set of cosets of $N$ in $G$ form a group under set multiplication - this is the quotient group $G/ N$.

I'm trying to improve my intuition for the concept of a quotient group, which seems rather unnatural to me at first. While considering the property that a quotient group partitions the original group, I arrived at the following question motivated by the converse idea:

Suppose $G$ is a group. If $P$ is a partition of $G$ such that $P$ forms a group (under set multiplication), is there necessarily some normal subgroup $N \le G$ such that $P$ is the quotient group $G/N$?

This may well be trivial, but I could not see how to prove it (or find a counterexample).

My intuition is as follows: a normal subgroup of $G$ in some way characterises part of the 'structure' of $G$, and this gives rise to 'structure' in the set of its cosets. If a partition also exhibits 'structure', this element of structure will presumably be present in some subgroup of $G$, and this would suggest a relation between the two. I'm not really sure that this is meaningful, but if anyone could either correct or elaborate upon this thinking that would be very helpful.

Comment: Maybe see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2388268/partition-of-a-group-to-have-normal-subgroup).

Comment: The quotient group is not "rather unnatural". The examples given seem very natural. Like $G=\Bbb Z$, $N=n\Bbb Z$ or $G=S_n$ and $N=A_n$ etc.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I'm certainly willing to believe that, and I agree for your examples. I'm just trying to refine my understanding having met the definition for the first time - I only mean 'unnatural' in the sense of 'unfamiliar' from my own prior experience.

Comment: @quanticbolt Thanks - I hadn't found that question when searching but it seems to be what I'm looking for.

Comment: @RAllen Yes, of course I understand. It is only that if you write a post about every new definition you read, this will become intense also. Sometimes it is good to have a bit experience with a new definition, do some examples and then ask later, if the first doubts are cleared by themselves.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I take your point. Perhaps my remark was superfluous to the question, which was intended more about the proof than the definition.